# Write an expression as a full derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a command that tells Mathematica to try to write the terms (if possible) of an expression as total derivates? Example: I want to tell mathematica to write

```
-Sin[t]+g[t]
```

as

```
D[Cos[t],t]+g[t]
```

instead. Is this possible?

Mathematically, this is basically (up to some constants) equivalent of Mathematica testing if the terms are analytically integrable (i.e. if they have closed form expressions).

Answer (score 6):

Here I define the expression and integrate it term by term using `Distribute`. Then I differentiate each term but with a `Defer` wrapping it, so the derivatives aren't actually carried out. FInally, I replace the terms that weren't integrated by the original function:

```
expression = -Sin[t] + g[t]

(* ==> g[t] - Sin[t] *)

integrals = Distribute[Integrate[expression, t]]

(* ==> Cos[t] + \[Integral]g[t] \[DifferentialD]t *)

original = 
 Map[Defer[D[#, t]] &, integrals] /. 
  Defer[D[Integrate[f_, __], _]] :> f
```

> $\partial_t \text{Cos}[t] + \text{g}[t]$

The reason I used `Defer` is that it allows you to copy the output and evaluate it by pasting it in a new cell. You could alternatively replace `Defer` with `HoldForm` if you want a more "stable" output. Then you have to explicitly use `ReleaseHold` if you want to evaluate the derivatives in the output expression.

Comment: I'll try this at once. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what is the role of e.g. (* ==> g[t] - Sin[t] *) is.  Do I need to change that if I want to use different functions instead of Sin t and g[t]? @Jens

Comment: @LoveLearning No, those things in `(* ... *)` are *Mathematica* comments that I only included to show what the output of the previous line is.

Comment: Yeah I noticed after some playing around. I thought `"..."` = comments but I guess...